# variable extraction from expression

Tags: javascript, algorithm, uglifyjs

I have below question and got no clue for it:

for expression in string:  `"func1( A+ func2(A)+ func3(B)+ C + 4 )"` need a way to identify all variables, in this case are A , B, C.  expression can be different so it should not be hard coded to just this pattern. for example:  it could just be `func1(A)+func2(B)`, and variables are A and B.

a little background:  still take `"func1( A+ func2(A)+ func3(B)+ C + 4 )"` as an example,  say I have other expressions for A : `"A=sum(a)"` and `"B=sum(b)"` and `"C=sum(c)"`, I want to do a merge so that first expression becomes: `"func1( sum(a)+ func2(sum(a))+ func3(sum(b))+ sum(c)+4)"`, in order to achieve this, I guess I need a way to identify all variables from the first expression, that's how the question comes.

Edit: just realized this is a little similar to a js minification process... just added uglifyjs tag to this question

any answers or clues are much appreciated!

**Solved: This was solved with exprima.js which works with AST. Please check accepted answer and commnets**

Comment: do those expressions follow a grammar? how are they generated? how do you define a variable?

Comment: grammar for the expression is a normal javascript function calls in string and can be mixed with operators (+ - * / and parenthesis), just basic grammar and is for other language as well. And variables are defined as a name string that are involved in such expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you most of the way there.  One problem I see you might have is that functions are also variables in JavaScript, so you'll have to pick out all of the variables (Identifiers) that aren't callees.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#out').text(
    JSON.stringify(
      esprima.parse("func1( A+ func2(A)+ func3(B)+ C + 4 )"),
      null, 2
    )
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jquery/esprima/2.7.1/esprima.js"></script>
<pre id='out'>

</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to edit my post saying that I solved this with esprima and I saw your comment! what a coincidence! I will accept this answer, and for ppl who need this, if you need all tokens you can call  esprima.parse(express,{tokens:true}) it will list all tokens for you as an extra array in result.

Comment: @AaronL Thank you for not trying to do it with a regex :)